# Getting error when tryhing to create this MySQL function

Tags: mysql, function, syntax-error

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  I'm trying to create a MySQL function like so ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION join_book(text VARCHAR) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 
AS  'SELECT DISTINCT e.subject_id FROM category c, resource_category rc, product_resource pr, product p, product_ebook pe, ebook e WHERE c.id = rc.category_id AND rc.resource_id = pr.resource_id AND pr.product_id = p.id AND p.id = pe.product_id AND pe.ebook_id = e.id AND c.id = $1'  
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

but I'm getting the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 
AS  'SELECT DISTINCT e.subject_id FROM categ' at line 1
```

Not sure what htis means.  Grateful for any help.

**Edit:**  I changed the function to be the following ...

```
CREATE FUNCTION join_book(text VARCHAR) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 
AS  'SELECT DISTINCT e.subject_id FROM category c, resource_category rc, product_resource pr, product p, product_ebook pe, ebook e WHERE c.id = rc.category_id AND rc.resource_id = pr.resource_id AND pr.product_id = p.id AND p.id = pe.product_id AND pe.ebook_id = e.id AND c.id = $1'  
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

but got the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS  'SELECT DISTINCT e.subject_id FROM category c, resource_category rc, s' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the VARCHAR size -- it's expecting `(text VARCHAR(N))`.  Generally, MySQL error text starts right where it sees the error; in this case, it's saying "I was expecting something other than ') RETURNS'" -- specifically, it was expecting ")) RETURNS".

Comment: Hi, I changed the syntax per your suggestion -- adding in "VARCHAR(32)", but instead got a different, equally baffling syntax error ("ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS  'SELECT DISTINCT e.subject_id FROM category c, resource_category rc, s' at line 2")

Comment: Check out the manual for creating functions and stored procedures: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html.  `IMMUTABLE` is not an option (`[NOT] DETERMINISTIC`); there doesn't appear to be support for `AS` in the way you're using it; I don't see any examples with quoted bodies.